# Can't find jetty config file on Fedora 28

Tags: java, fedora, configuration-management, jetty

I installed jetty8 on fedora 28, but I do not know where is the configuration file for the server. In Ubuntu the jetty8 configuration file is /etc/default/jetty8.

To install jetty I've used:

> dnf install jetty8

Comment: I've used dnf install jetty8

Comment: That type of information should be edited into the question.  The question should be moved to Unix/Linux stack.

Comment: Add java tag too.  My reading indicates most of the config is done for the instances, but there's an ini file in the base installation folder for jetty.  http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quick-start-configure.html

Comment: Interesting. jetty 9 has a systemd unit and can be configured from `/etc/default/jetty` but I don't see anything for jetty8. I suspect it's just there for backward compatibility with legacy code and you should already have something in place to run your old code. If the Jetty version doesn't matter, I'd rollback that installation and then install `jetty` (9.4.x today).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, I've installed jetty 9. Now I can see the configuration files in /etc/jetty.